# Get first value using condition

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

**Case:**

I'm trying to display fist name using a condition in Kusto.
For Example:

| first_name | second_name | type | score | date. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Adam | student | 67. | 2021-8-4 |
| John | Adam | student | 89. | 2021-8-3 |
| John | Adam | student | 75. | 2021-8-2 |
| James | Smith | student | 80. | 2021-8-2 |
| Sam | Miles | student | 69. | 2021-8-3 |

**Query needed:**

A query made the following:
if first name contains "J" then get first value of score column, if not let the value as is

**Expected result:**

| first_name | second_name | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | Adam | 67. |
| James | Smith | 80. |
| Sam | Miles | 69. |

Search for such operator like `case` or `iff` not success

Comment: "*get first value of score column*" - you'll need to clarify how the data set should be ordered, so that it's clear what *first* means (e.g., there's currently no datetime column to order by)

Comment: it is like when we use the top operation for a dataset, then we will get the first row. but i added the date to the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try this:

```
let T = datatable(first_name:string, second_name:string, type:string, score:int, timestamp:datetime)
[
    'John',  'Adam',  'student', 67, datetime(2021-08-04),
    'John',  'Adam',  'student', 89, datetime(2021-08-03),
    'John',  'Adam',  'student', 75, datetime(2021-08-02),
    'James', 'Smith', 'student', 80, datetime(2021-08-02),
    'Sam',   'Miles', 'student', 69, datetime(2021-08-03),
]
;
T
| where first_name startswith "J"
| summarize arg_max(timestamp, *) by first_name
| union (
    T
    | where first_name !startswith "J"
)
| project first_name, second_name, score
```

| first_name | second_name | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sam | Miles | 69 |
| John | Adam | 67 |
| James | Smith | 80 |